# Reading a specific column from an excel sheet based on an MS-word VBA macro

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I would like to highlight specific words given in a specific column of an excel sheet in a word document.

I have a working solution (see below) that reads the words from a word file but I can not get it running to do the same thing using a specific column from an excel file. Essentially I want to do what the following python code does (but for VBA):

```
import pandas as pd
all = pd.read_excel("list.xlsx")
docRef = all(all["MY COLUMN NAME"])
```

... and the docRef should be used in the code below. I just cant get it running ...

```
Sub highlightWords()

Dim sCheckDoc As String
Dim docRef As Document
Dim docCurrent As Document
Dim wrdRef As Object

sCheckDoc = "list.docx"
Set docCurrent = Selection.Document
Set docRef = Documents.Open(sCheckDoc)
docCurrent.Activate

Options.DefaultHighlightColorIndex = wdRed
With Selection.Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.Highlight = True
    .Replacement.Text = "^&"
    .Forward = True
    .Format = True
    .MatchWholeWord = True
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWildcards = False
End With

For Each wrdRef In docRef.Words
    If Asc(Left(wrdRef, 1)) > 32 Then
        With Selection.Find
            .Wrap = wdFindContinue
            .Text = wrdRef
            .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
        End With
    End If
Next wrdRef

docRef.Close
docCurrent.Activate
End Sub
```

Code modified from [here](https://wordribbon.tips.net/T001173_Highlight_Words_from_a_Word_List.html).

Comment: Code you have performs a search on a Word file (as you stated). Can you provide the code that you tried for an Excel file? we can than help you with any issues that you have

Comment: Well I have tried a lot of things - in the simplest version just replacing "list.docx" with my "list.xlsx" file (assuming that an excel file is also a document and all readers are inherited from the same class). Then replacing the Document with Workbook (found that on google) but it says then undefined type, object required, 404 etc. In principle I just need the 3 lines of pyhton code running in VBA (where I am unforunatly not very familar with the syntax)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to control Excel from within Word you should set a reference to the Excel library in the Word VBA editor : Tools, References, scroll down to Microsoft Excel and tick it.

Then you need to open Excel, and load the workbook

```
   Dim XL as new Excel.Application
   Dim wb as Excel.Workbook
   Set wb = xl.Workbooks.open("path and name of file list.xlsx")
   For Each wordref in wb.Sheets(1).Range("a1:A" & wb.Sheets(1).usedrange.rows.count)
```